# Tooling API - UserFieldAccess - Receiving UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION error

Tags: soql, tooling-api

I was hoping someone might be able to shed some light on this error please.

Error is:
UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION
[object Object]: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 636017422-78720 (1319304334)

SOQL (using Tooling APi in Developer Console) is:

```
SELECT DurableId,EntityDefinitionId,FieldDefinitionId,Id,IsAccessible,IsCreatable,IsUpdatable,UserId FROM UserFieldAccess where DurableId IN ('Contact.00Nw0000003fCQgEAM.0054J000002EgGB','Contact.00Nw0000003fCQhEAM.0054J000002EgGB','Contact.00Nw0000003fCQiEAM.0054J000002EgGB','Contact.00Nw0000003fDNpEAM.0054J000002EgGB','Contact.00Nw00000088K1TEAU.0054J000002EgGB','Contact.00Nw00000088K1UEAU.0054J000002EgGB','Contact.00Nw00000089CgnEAE.0054J000002EgGB')
```

*'Contact.00Nw0000003fCQgEAM.0054J000002EgGB' - Contact is the object, '00Nw0000003fCQgEAM' is the custom field ID and '0054J000002EgGB' is the UserId.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: out of curiosity, what are you trying to accomplish overall? Otherwise, for this specific question, what happens when you whittle down your list of `DurableId` until you get a working query? Likewise, does each DurableId work on its own `DurableId=xxxx`?

Comment: Hi Kris, I'm trying to get the Users permissions for custom fields (e.g. read, write), preferably I'd like to get it per Profile but this seemed the only way.  If I try a simple query like: SELECT DurableId,EntityDefinitionId,FieldDefinitionId,Id,IsAccessible,IsCreatable,IsUpdatable,UserId FROM UserFieldAccess where DurableId ='Contact.00Nw0000003fCQgEAM.0054J000002EgGB'   I still get an error: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION [object Object]: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1401140523-76787 (26322)

Comment: What's the context - are you in salesforce in code, in an external app, just auditing things, etc. Have you looked at the metadata api & [profiles](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profile.htm) with custom field permissions? In terms of your error, have you tried all your identified fields as the sole criteria? They all fail with the same error? Are these all custom fields of your creation or from a package?

Comment: I'm using the Developer Console. I'll take a look at the Profile object. Not sure how to try 'all your identified fields as the sole criteria'. These are a mixture of custom fields of User creation and there will be some from various packages.

Comment: + Yes, had forgotten I'd already downloaded the 'Profile' object using this: SELECT Id,CreatedById,CreatedDate,Description,LastModifiedById,LastModifiedDate,Name FROM Profile

Comment: As I understood it, (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/370776/retrieving-results-from-userfieldaccess-using-durableid/370792#370792) I needed to query the UserFieldAcess object using ObjectName.FieldId.UserId criteria.

Comment: I'm talking about debugging your issue to narrow down what fields are throwing an error and which do not. Query each field on its own against `UserFieldAccess` and see which work and don't work out of your list of fields from `IN()`. I only get this similar error if I query against a field that doesn't exist in my current org. Are you on the system admin profile?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce it, with the same stacktrace error Id, and noted the following behavior:

- An **error is thrown** when using the **18-digit** [FieldDefinition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_fielddefinition.htm) Id for your custom field within `DurableId`
- The **query works correctly** when using the **15-digit Id** for your custom field

Based on your question, it seems you're using the *18-digit version* (`00Nw0000003fCQgEAM`). I'm not sure how you got that, but you really want to use the format given by querying as mentioned in [UserFieldAccess](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_userfieldaccess.htm), `DurableId`

> Unique identifier for the field. **Always retrieve this value before
> using it, as the value isn’t guaranteed to stay the same from one
> release to the next**

You should be using whatever format it gives you from `FieldDefinition` as any change (in this case, 18-digit vs. 15-digit) will throw the above error.

If you take the `DurableId` exactly as it's returned from the query in your other question

```sql
SELECT DeveloperName, DurableId
FROM FieldDefinition 
WHERE EntityDefinitionId = 'Contact'
```

`DurableId` should, based on testing it, already be the correct format (15-digit Id) as needed:

`Contact.15DigitIdForCustomField`

Where you just need to append the User Id you're interested in (can be 15-digit or 18-digit version).

Answer (score -1):

Anytime you get `UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION` nobody outside of salesforce can tell what is the error as that is internal to salesforce. If you have support contract, create a case with them and they usually share details as to why that is happening.

Comment: Thanks Metasync, unfortunately Developer Support isnt included and have SF Support are unwilling to help.  I've tried the following query: SELECT DurableId,EntityDefinitionId,FieldDefinitionId,Id,IsAccessible,IsCreatable,IsUpdatable,UserId FROM UserFieldAccess where DurableId ='Contact.00Nw0000003fCQgEAM.0054J000002EgGBQA0'  - Contact is the object, '00Nw0000003fCQgEAM' is the custom field id, and '0054J000002EgGBQA0' is the UserId - all verified as being correct and the custom field is not part of an installed package.

Comment: Also, from this post: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/370776/retrieving-results-from-userfieldaccess-using-durableid/370792#370792  I thought i had the correct format of the query, i.e. ObjectApiName.FieldNameOrId.UserId